# MacOS Solarized Color-scheme not working in Terminal VIM

Tags: vim, terminal, color-scheme

I followed Ethan's Guides for configuring solarized. In particular I:

- Downloaded and set his Solarized Dark ansi profile for OS X Terminal
- Downloaded and moved solarized theme to vim/colors
- I then added the two lines `set background=dark` and `colorscheme solarized` to my vimrc
- Also downloaded macvim and linked vim to macvims vim

After doing this I get an ugly vim with green lines and the colors are not quite right. I tried using the 256 color version also with adding the option `let g:solarized_termcolors=256` and while it looked a little better it wasn't quite right and I would rather do it the native way with the solarized terminal theme + ansi colors.

[Ugly Solarized Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPo0U.png)

[macOS Terminal Profile Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1EQy.png)

Also here is my vimrc:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

" javascript syntax highlighting
Plugin 'jelera/vim-javascript-syntax'

" indentation help
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plugin 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides'

" bracket and quote help
Plugin 'Raimondi/delimitMate'

" YouCompleteMe
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'

" Tern
Plugin 'marijnh/tern_for_vim'

" Surround.vim
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'

" Fuzzy file search
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

" map ctrl + c to automatically delimit brackets and quotes
imap <C-c> <CR><Esc>O

" fuck ex mode
nnoremap Q <nop>

" you complete me tweaks
let g:ycm_add_preview_to_completeopt=0
let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf=0
set completeopt-=preview

" general options
syntax on
set number
set expandtab
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set guifont=Menlo:h12
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
set showbreak=↪

let g:indent_guides_start_level=2
let g:indent_guides_guide_size=1
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Solarized can't look "right" in a terminal emulator advertising itself as "256color-ready" because not a single color in its palette matches with any of colors 16-255 of [the standard xterm palette](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg). Contrary to what the official blurb might make you think, the Solarized palette *is very poorly suited for terminal usage* and the Vim colorscheme is not very well written at all so don't get too dreamy about that typical blue background.
2. That said, there are two *hypothetical* ways to make Solarized look "right" in a terminal:

   - set up colors 0-15 of your terminal emulator and make sure both Solarized and Vim only use those colors,
   - or, if your terminal emulator and your Vim build allow it, use `:help 'termguicolors'` to force Vim to use "true colors". Hint: Terminal.app doesn't support that feature.
3. Your Solarized terminal palette is broken: those are the default colors, not the Solarized colors.
4. Don't waste your time on that crap. There are plenty of competently written colorschemes at your disposal.